# Magento 2: Uicomponent grid filter with multiple values as url params

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, filter, data-provider, ui-grid

In this example

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
        <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="status" xsi:type="string">*</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

How to filter uicomponent grid with multiple url param values ? Like 1,2 not all the values

Comment: try to add in components xml file <filterUrlParams>
                <param name="custom_value">*</param>
            </filterUrlParams>

Answer (score 3):

If you have a requirement as load an admin grid with pre-defined multiple filter values like below:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
        <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="status" xsi:type="string">1,2</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Then you can go in the **`dataprovider`** class of the uicomponent grid and make below changes(add below **`prepareUpdateUrl`** function code):

```
protected function prepareUpdateUrl() {
    if (!isset($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'])) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'] as $paramName => $paramValue) {
        if ('*' == $paramValue) {
            $paramValue = $this->request->getParam($paramName);
        }
        if ($paramValue) {
            $this->data['config']['update_url'] = sprintf(
                    '%s%s/%s', $this->data['config']['update_url'], $paramName, $paramValue
            );
            if ($paramName == 'status') {
                $paramValue = explode(',', $paramValue);
                $this->addFilter(
                        $this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('in')->create()
                );
            } else {
                $this->addFilter(
                        $this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('eq')->create()
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In above code,
I am checking paramName as **`if ($paramName == 'status')`** then explode this **paramValue** as **`$paramValue = explode(',', $paramValue);`** and adding a new filter as below:

**`$this->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('in')->create());`**

And changing the **filter condition** from **`eq`** to **`in`**.
This solution is very well tested and working live in one of my module, so let me know if you face any issue.
Thanks :)

If this scenario didn't work for you. Try this:
Use preference to override Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider

Now add this function in your file:

```
protected function prepareUpdateUrl()
    {
        if (!isset($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'])) {
            return;
        }
        foreach ($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'] as $paramName => $paramValue) {
            if ('*' == $paramValue) {
                $paramValue = $this->request->getParam($paramName);
            }
            if ($paramValue) {
                $this->data['config']['update_url'] = sprintf(
                    '%s%s/%s/',
                    $this->data['config']['update_url'],
                    $paramName,
                    $paramValue
                );

                if ($this->getName() == 'your_data_source_name') {
                    $paramValue = explode(',', $paramValue);
                    $this->addFilter(
                        $this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('in')->create()
                    );
                } else {
                    $this->addFilter(
                        $this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('eq')->create()
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think this will be effective and we can add multiple conditions in it based on the requirement! Thanks!

Comment: Where to add `prepareUpdateUrl()` function?

Comment: add in your dataprovider class of the uicomponent grid, if you are using default one in the uicomponent grid, then create your own dataprovider by extending the default one and extend the prepareUpdateUrl function ...

Comment: Can't believe this answer didn't have any votes. It works perfectly.

Comment: This functionality works fine. Thanks!

Comment: For those who don't know or confused where to use the prepareUpdateUrl method. Use preference to override Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider. Then add that function there. You can differentiate the data source by $this->getName()

Comment: @Jason I think using preference is not a good approch because by using preference this prepareUpdateUrl will be look for if $this->getName() == 'your_data_source_name' for each uicomponent grid while filter even if they dont have such filter. But if all the uicomponent grid having this kind of filter then we can go with preference.

And if we have few partcular uicomponent grid that need this kind of filter then it is better to extend this class in custom module and modify and use in the particular uicomponent grid.

Please tell me your thought on it.

Comment: In my case I have 3 grids for similar customization. I don't have a data provider. If possible can you share how to add a custom data provider for a grid?